# What can lead to "IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)" exception with python requests?

Tags: python, http, python-3.x, exception, python-requests

I have a URL which i cannot `get()` with `requests` module, maybe due to a response encoding error.

Here is pseudo:

```
import requests
r = requests.get(url) # exception
```

Traceback:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 614, in _readinto_chunked
chunk_left = self._read_next_chunk_size()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 559, in _read_next_chunk_size
return int(line, 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: b''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 616, in generate
decode_content=True):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 225, in stream
data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 174, in read
data = self._fp.read(amt)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 500, in read
return super(HTTPResponse, self).read(amt)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 529, in readinto
return self._readinto_chunked(b)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 618, in _readinto_chunked
raise IncompleteRead(bytes(b[0:total_bytes]))
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 8, in http_request_hook
return action(url, params = payload, cookies = cookies, headers = headers)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
return request('get', url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 455, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 558, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 394, in send
r.content
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 679, in content
self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 619, in generate
raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)
```

HTTP 1.1

What may be the reason?

UPD: After sometime, i don't have a link anymore, but i may add that this link was from website that has some sort of protection from bots and i wanted to challenge the author of the algorithm. But eventually failed by any means.

Comment: Hi - you need to include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get good help on this problem here.

Comment: I cannot share the URL, it's irrelevant (all you need to know is that it's public and massively visited resource). Minimal and usable sample is in my original text. All errors are inside requests module. I copied request URL and headers i try to use right from browser inspector trace, so google chrome has no trouble with that request.

Comment: Request also fails with no extra query string or headers, like in my sample. of course.

Comment: Clearly the URL isn't irrelevant - providing it should be part of you providing a complete reproducible example of the problem. If you can't share the URL, then the only recourse is to quiz you. Have you tried using a protocol sniffer like Fiddler to see what's actually passing on the network? Or thinking about other ways of confirming that the url response is good/bad, have you tried using e.g. Poster to access the same URL, or a browser? Did these show any error?

Comment: Have to agree with @barny there.  Without the URL (or ***a*** URL that fails) it's not reproducible.